# Nginx: Serve static files over SSL on Android

Tags: android, static, nginx

I am developing a web application which will have to serve some static pdf files. Everything works great on desktop and iOS however static files are not downloaded on Android. It just hangs the download. Here is the screenshot of how that looks:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/r3qz9cia9vwwgam/2012-08-22%2020.38.37.png

Android version is 4.1.1

The nginx version is:

```
$ /usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.2.3
built by gcc 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/usr/local/nginx-1.2.3 --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_realip_module
```

Here is main portion of the nginx config:

```
server {
    server_name .foosite.com;
    listen 443;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/foo.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/foo.key;

    access_log logs/foo.log;

    gzip                on;
    gzip_http_version   1.0;
    gzip_comp_level     2;
    gzip_proxied        any;
    gzip_min_length     1100;
    gzip_buffers        16 8k;
    gzip_types          text/plain text/html text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    # Some version of IE 6 don't handle compression well on some mime-types, so just disable for them
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6].(?!.*SV1)";

    # Set a vary header so downstream proxies don't send cached gzipped content to IE6
    gzip_vary on;

    location / {
        # some proxy_pass stuff here        
    }

    location /media {
        alias   /foo/path/to/media/;
        expires 1y;
    }
}
```

Here are the response headers I get using curl:

```
$ curl -I https://foosite.com/media/path/to/foopdf.pdf
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.2.3
Date: Thu, 23 Aug 2012 00:40:16 GMT
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Length: 136833
Last-Modified: Wed, 22 Aug 2012 21:14:50 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Expires: Fri, 23 Aug 2013 00:40:16 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=31536000
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

I also tried to mimic my chrome android browser by providing the user agent header:

```
$ curl -A "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.1.1; Nexus 7 Build/JRO03D) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.166  Safari/535.19" -I https://foosite.com/media/path/to/foopdf.pdf
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.2.3
Date: Thu, 23 Aug 2012 00:33:09 GMT
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Length: 136833
Last-Modified: Wed, 22 Aug 2012 21:14:50 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Expires: Fri, 23 Aug 2013 00:33:09 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=31536000
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

Any ideas as to why this is happening? Again, this issue is only affecting all my android devices (Galaxy Nexus and Nexus 7). On desktop and iOS devices it works fine. And if I disable SSL and serve over port 80, then everything works fine.

Thank you.

Comment: Anything in the logcat, like a 'This certificate is not from a trusted authority'? If you are using a self-signed cert, you can search SO as there are known issues with Android and self-signed certs.

Comment: What is logcat? I check the foo.log (using standard formula) file and in there the response is with code 200. SSL is from https://startssl.com/. In Chrome (even on Android) it shows with green icon, so I can assume it validates just fine.

Comment: Actually you are right. I figured out what is logcat and I see `Cannot verify hostname` error there. So I guess that is what causes the download failure. Any suggestions as to how to fix it?

Comment: A quick search brings up http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9709 which although for mail points to a possible alternate server name not in cert issue.

Comment: I created and android issue for this. I describe it there in more detail. http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=36599